# Pass Angular scope value to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I checked the existing similar questions in SO but I think it is bit different. I am aware we don't need to use JavaScript along with Angular. But due to some dependencies, I am using it.

```
var ProfileApp = angular.module('ProfileApp', []);
     ProfileApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http,$location){
   $scope.searchok = 1; 

   $scope.tn_id = '5';
-- Some Angular Codes are here ---
```

I want to put **$scope.tn_id** value to JavaScript variable. I tried to like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var tn_id_from_angular;

</script>
```

Defined the variable before Angular code. Added below code inside Angular code like this.

```
   tn_id_from_angular = $scope.tn_id;
alert (tn_id_from_angular);
```

When I run the code I am getting the alert box but it is not showing the value and giving me error undefined.

### Edit

In simple words, I want to assign **$scope.tn_id**  value to javascript variable **tn_id_from_angular**.

Comment: What is shown should work fine technically. Sounds more like `$scope.tn_id` is undefined when you try this assignment and alert. Show full code context where you call the alert. Also need to understand that angular ***is*** javascript

Comment: You are right. I was calling it on file load and due to some reason, it angular didn't load until that time. Now I moved it to button click then it worked. Very stupid I was.

Answer (score 1):

you can assign a global variable to the `window` object, and then retrieve it

*warning: this is hacky territory.. we are not making good code here, but it might work*

try this in your angular code:

```
// ...

var ProfileApp = angular.module('ProfileApp', []);
ProfileApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http,$location){
  $scope.searchok = 1;
  $scope.tn_id = '5';
  window.hacks = {tn_id_from_angular: $scope.tn_id};

// ...
```

and then this in your script:

```
const {tn_id_from_angular} = window.hacks;
alert (tn_id_from_angular);
```

so long as the script executes *after* the angular code does -- it should work

if it doesn't, then you need to figure out some kind of "angular ready callback"

Comment: You are really just making what OP was doing more verbose

Comment: verbose — read — *explicit.* always a good thing when you're installing cryptic hacks